# Eliminate empty string values in databound combobox C#

Tags: c#, mysql, data-binding, combobox, string

I have more than 30 comboboxes in my application which I bound with MySQL database, but every combobox shows data and empty string under it both. How can I ignore empty strings and only show string values?

this is my code:

```
void combobox()
{
    string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';port='{1}';database='{2}';username=uwloanmanmain;password=**************;Connect Timeout=180;Command Timeout=180", dbserverip.Text,curport.Text,currentdb.Text);
    string Query = "select * from waqrtiff.customconditions ;";
    MySqlConnection conwaqDatabasecc = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conwaqDatabasecc);
    MySqlDataReader myreader666;

    try
    {
        conwaqDatabasecc.Open();
        myreader666 = cmdwaqDatabase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myreader666.Read())
        {
            string sName = myreader666.GetString("50079");
            50079combobox.Items.Add(sName);

            string sName2 = myreader666.GetString("bauth");
            bauthcombobox.Items.Add(sName2);

            string sName3 = myreader666.GetString("myact");
            myacttcombobox.Items.Add(sName3);

            string sName4 = myreader666.GetString("payscale");
            payscalecombox.Items.Add(sName4);

            string sName5 = myreader666.GetString("returns");
            returnsscombobox.Items.Add(sName5);

            string sName6 = myreader666.GetString("report");
            reportcombobox.Items.Add(sName6);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    conwaqDatabasecc.Close();
```

}

Comment: Check if `string` value `IsNullOrEmpty` before inserting. For example for the `sName` - `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName)) { 50079combobox.Items.Add(sName); }`. Do same for all values.

Comment: @michaelmoore  I don't know how to thank you sir :) it worked :) thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place a simple if statement around all .add.

```
  string sName = myreader666.GetString("50079");
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sName))
{
  50079combobox.Items.Add(sName);
}
```